# Algorithm to reduce a cost of a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I have to check if a new weighted arc (from an existing node to another existing node) given by the user can decrease the weight of an undirected weighted connected graph without modifying the original graph. The graph has `N` nodes and `N-1` arcs. This new arc must keep the graph connected.

Do you know of any algorithm that can solve the problem efficiently?
I have to develop it with Java.

Comment: What is the weight of an undirected weighted graph?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the definition of the weight of an undirected graph, then your first job is to write a function that will calculate such weight given a graph. Once this is done, you can simply loop through all possible additional arc and call your function to figure out which assignment provides the minimum weight.